# Browserify standalone option doesn't directly wraps the code with specified name?

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I tried to use gulp, browserify, watchify, and babelify to compile a standalone js module.
The options is like this:

```
const browserifyOpts = {
  debug: true,
  entries: path.join('src', 'index.js'),
  standalone: 'Goo',
  transform: [
    'babelify',
  ],
};
```

My JS module is as follows:

```
export default class Goo {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'hello';
  }
}
```

It compiles fine. But when I include it in a script tag in a html file, the Goo module is wrapped inside window.Goo.default, that is, I cannot directly use:

```
new Goo();
```

but have to use:

```
new Goo.default();
```

Any idea where went wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option would be to wrap this yourself by having your `index.js` file contain something like

```
module.exports = require('./main').default;
```

and move your current `index.js` to `main.js`. Then you'll be set.

As the other answer says, you can potentially use [babel-plugin-add-module-exports](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports), but that is not something I'd generally recommend because while it fixes this problem, it also introduces the possibility that you could accidentally write import/export pairs that work but are not spec-compliant.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Babel 6 handles default module exports differently. If you want to use the legacy version, you can use the [add-module-exports](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) plugin.

Either add that into your `.babelrc`, or add it as an option in Babelify.

More information from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/156):

> has to do with the new way Babel handles default exports. if you dont
>   want to have to reference the default key, you need to use this
>   plugin: https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports